# How to direct print to a specific printer and not showing a print dialog?

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have this [EDRAW LINK](https://www.edrawsoft.com/embed-word-vbnet.php). I able to do his guide on how to browse and print a MS Word. But in print button I don't want to show the print dialog instead it will direct print. I search in google but it gives an example of `Print Document`

I Used the following Code:

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    AxEDOffice1.SetActivePrinter("Printer Name")
    AxEDOffice1.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PaperSize = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4
    AxEDOffice1.PrintDialog()
End Sub
```

It is showing a `PrintDialog`.

Comment: always provide your Code!!

Comment: @Hadi this is my whole code in my button.

Comment: i added it. you have to add it in each question. To show to other users what have you tried or your question will be downvoted and will not take attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Use `PrintOut()` Method to achieve this:

```
AxEDOffice1.PrintOut(EDOfficeLib.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument)
```

Comment: The result of this is exporting a `XPS` file. but not printing :(

Comment: @KiRa you are using xps printer as default. Check the default printer name you provided

Comment: @KiRa your comment `The result of this is exporting a XPS file` means that your question is answered :)